# prevent default anchor behavior in IE7 without library/framework

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, anchor

I have a link like so

```
<a onclick="return false;" href="http://somesite.com">my link</a>
```

In firefox, chrome and safari this link does not do anything when you click it. When in IE7 the link still goes to http://somesite.com. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I am not using any frameworks like jquery, just raw javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a onclick="window.event && (event.returnValue = false); return false;" href="http://somesite.com">hi</a>
```

Comment: this works good, but I don't think you need the second return false; thanks

Comment: This will only work in IE and throw an "'event' undefined"-Error in other browsers.

Comment: I have confirmed the above comment, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

According to some sites, `event.returnValue = false;` should help. Of course other browsers will throw an error because they don't support returnValue, so you should check for that. [This article](http://11heavens.com/IE7-bug-report-onclick-event-handler) even proposes to remove the href attribute on-click :-)

Fail-save should be

```
<a onclick="...; if (window.event && typeof window.event.returnValue == 'boolean') return window.event.returnValue = false; return false;" href="http://somesite.com">hi</a>
```

Using js to add the eventListener, you could also use `event.preventDefault();` in standard-compliant browsers where event is the argument given to the listener function.

Comment: this does not enter the if statement when in IE7

Comment: Why not? Did you replace the ellipsis with your action code (respectively remove it when there's no action)?

Comment: Other browsers won't throw an error if they don't support `returnValue` - the statement `event.returnValue = false;` will simply create a new property on the `event` object if it doesn't already exist, and browsers that don't use that property will ignore it.

Comment: what is an ellipsis? I used the code exactly as posted above, without the ...; and it works in firefox, but in IE7 it still goes to the link.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I thought about browsers that don't support window.event. Or is that a standard for js functions in html attributes?

Comment: Well I thought it was reasonably standard to support `event` (without needing the `window.` prefix) within inline handlers. Perhaps the latest browsers have dropped support for that, but still testing for event object should be enough, you shouldn't need to also test for the `returnValue` property before setting it. In any case I've never previously needed more than a simple `return false;`  - I thought all browsers supported that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `"return false;"` has always worked for me in IE. I don't have IE7 available to test with, but it worked for me just now in IE8, and I'm sure it used to work in IE6.

Still, you could try something like the following:

```
<a onclick="return cancelDefault();" href="http://somesite.com">my link</a>

<script>
function cancelDefault(e) {
   if (!e) e = window.event;
   e.returnValue = false;
   return false;
}
</script>
```

Browsers that don't support `returnValue` will simply ignore it: they don't mind if you create a new property of that name on the event object.

Comment: Well as I said, it worked for me in IE8 (I tested it before posting my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this(with inspiration from some of the other answers)

```
<script>
function stopIEAnchor(){
   if (typeof window.event !== "undefined") 
      return window.event.returnValue = false; 

    return false;
}
</script>

<a onclick="return stopIEAnchor()" href="http://somesite.com">link</a>
```

I will keep this question open for a while longer to see if we can get anymore solutions or input.